# file size c is different than the size data string's size

Tags: c, windows, file

I have a file I'm writing to and then changing the size of it to the size of text written to it something like:

```
FILE * file...
```

I get all the data from the file and change the file's size to the data's size but it differs. The string's size is smaller then the filelength and it cuts it and loses data.
What might be the problem?

```
while(fgets(cLine, sizeof(cLine), file) )
    str.append((string)cLine);
fputs(str.c_str(),file);
_chsize( fileno(file), (int)str.size() );
```

When I checked it always `fileLength(fileno(file))` is larger than `str.size()`!

Comment: That doesn't look like C. Do you want C or C++?

Comment: I'm using teh file from c but I need c++ (I'm aware of fstream but for mu purpose I need c

Comment: the way you change the file size is incorrect. you rely on incorrect assumption that file size should be the same as the number of characters contained within a string.

Comment: why is it incorrect I think that's what I want to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps it's CRLF? Beware of:

`fopen(filename, "r")` vs `fopen(filename, "rb")`,

and likewise

`fopen(filename, "w")` vs `fopen(filename, "wb")`.

The reason is because `"r"` or `"w"` will translate CRLF, while `"rb"` or `"wb"` will treat the data as binary. On most platforms this is ignored. For instance, the [fopen man page on OS X](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/freopen.3.html):

> The mode string can also include the
>   letter "b" either as a third
>   character or as a character between
>   the characters in any of the
>   two-character strings described above.
>   This is strictly for compatibility
>   with ISO/IEC 9899:1990 ("ISO C90")
>   and has no effect; the "b" is
>   ignored.

The [fopen page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) says something different:

> **b**
>
> Open in binary (untranslated) mode;
>   translations involving carriage-return
>   and linefeed characters are
>   suppressed.
>
> If **t** or **b** is not given in mode, the
>   default translation mode is defined by
>   the global variable [_fmode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee2849wt.aspx). If **t** or **b**
>   is prefixed to the argument, the
>   function fails and returns **NULL**.
>
> For more information about using text
>   and binary modes in Unicode and
>   multibyte stream-I/O, see [Text and
>   Binary Mode File I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktss1a9b.aspx) and [Unicode
>   Stream I/O in Text and Binary Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4cy2b8e.aspx).

Comment: everything workd fine untill I tried to change file's size 
this is the way I opened 
file=_fsopen(path.c_str(),"r+",_SH_DENYRW)
but the file's length and it text's size differ???

Comment: What happened is that you opened the file in "text mode", which means that the file operations are attempting to translate for CRLF. Since that's obviously a Windows system call, it's turning LF into CRLF when you write to the file.

Comment: the rb+ really solved the issue but what is teh difference between the "r" and "rb" will it affect anything else?

Comment: Binary mode means 'read the file as it is found on disk'.  It means your data will contain both CR and LF at the ends of lines.  Text mode ("r" and, I believe, "rt") will read the binary data, but maps CR LF to just LF to mark the ends of lines.  The other difference is the text mode is sensitive to control-Z characters appearing in the file - that is an antique (if not archaic) EOF indication mechanism.  A binary file will ignore such characters - it might read some bytes beyond that EOF mark.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing in your code for cr/lf and what OS you are running, there could be some translating happening in the background when you read/write the file if you open it in text mode.

Comment: what do you mean and what should I change in the cod eto handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan has hit the nail on the head.

Ensure that you are reading the file in binary format or if you are certain that the file only contains text (and that is all that you want) then be prepared for file characters to be in unicode or some other format.

You'll also find that extra control characters will be automatically added not least the EOF character.

My question though is why do you read the data from the file, only to write it back in again?

Comment: I do somehthings in between I wrote only teh idea